# [ROS2] image_transport only advertising raw option

Tags: ros2, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I created a ROS2 stereo camera node using image transport. I have two publisher:

```
m_publisher_left_image = image_transport::create_publisher(this, "stereo/left/image_raw");
m_publisher_right_image = image_transport::create_publisher(this, "stereo/right/image_raw");
m_publisher_left_info = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo>("stereo/left/camera_info", 10);
m_publisher_right_info = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::CameraInfo>("stereo/right/camera_info", 10);
```

When I start the node on my laptop I can see the following topics with ros2 topic list:

```
/stereo/left/camera_info
/stereo/left/image_raw
/stereo/left/image_raw/compressed
/stereo/left/image_raw/compressedDepth
/stereo/left/image_raw/theora
/stereo/right/camera_info
/stereo/right/image_raw
/stereo/right/image_raw/compressed
/stereo/right/image_raw/compressedDepth
/stereo/right/image_raw/theora
```

Now I run the exact same code on a Jetson Nano, also using eloquent distro but I can only see

```
/stereo/left/camera_info
/stereo/left/image_raw
/stereo/right/camera_info
/stereo/right/image_raw
```

I install eloquent via  debian packages in late Nov on my laptop. On the Jetson it was installed on 6th Jan.

I would be glad if someone could explain me the cause of the different behavior.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341712/%5Bros2%5D-image_transport-only-advertising-raw-option/) by [tlaci](https://answers.ros.org/users/49859/tlaci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-14**:
Do you have the image transport plugins installed on your jetson nano?

**Comment by [tlaci](https://answers.ros.org/users/49859/tlaci/) on 2020-01-15**:
Yes, I have.

```
ros-eloquent-image-transport-plugins/bionic 2.2.1-1bionic.20191213.060222 amd64
A set of plugins for publishing and subscribing to sensor_msgs/Image topics in representations other than raw pixel data.
```

Edit: I have just realized that it says amd64 for all my packages. Shouldn't it be arm64? I installed ros2 according to the eloquent (debian packages) tutorial.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-01-15**:
If you're on the Jetson you should have arm64 assuming you're running an arm64 os image. The plugins certainly won't load if they are the wrong architecture.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-15**:
Sounds like we have a diagnosis!

**Comment by [tlaci](https://answers.ros.org/users/49859/tlaci/) on 2020-01-16**:
It works now. I thought image_transport_plugins should be installed with eloquent, for me it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I reinstalled eloquent choosing the right architecture. Somehow it is a problem if amd64 is listed in the brackets too, maybe because it finds amd64 packages first.

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'
```

After that I installed image_transport_plugins and now it works fine.

---

Originally posted by [tlaci](https://answers.ros.org/users/49859/tlaci/) with karma: 48 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1